# How to implement a PhaseListener which runs at end of lifecycle?

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, phaselistener

How can I implement a `PhaseListener` which runs at end of the JSF lifecycle?

Answer (score 44, accepted):

You need to implement the [`PhaseListener`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/event/PhaseListener.html) interface and hook on [`beforePhase()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/event/PhaseListener.html#beforePhase%28javax.faces.event.PhaseEvent%29) of the [`PhaseId_RENDER_RESPONSE`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/event/PhaseId.html#RENDER_RESPONSE). The render response is the last phase of the JSF lifecycle.

```java
public class MyPhaseListener implements PhaseListener {

    @Override
    public PhaseId getPhaseId() {
        return PhaseId.RENDER_RESPONSE;
    }

    @Override
    public void beforePhase(PhaseEvent event) {
        // Do your job here which should run right before the RENDER_RESPONSE.
    }

    @Override
    public void afterPhase(PhaseEvent event) {
        // Do your job here which should run right after the RENDER_RESPONSE.
    }

}
```

To get it to run, register it as follows in `faces-config.xml`:

```xml
<lifecycle>
    <phase-listener>com.example.MyPhaseListener</phase-listener>
</lifecycle>
```

---

**Update** the above phase listener is indeed applicaiton-wide. To have a phase listener for a specific view, use the `beforePhase` and/or `afterPhase` attributes of the [`<f:view>`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/javaserverfaces/2.1/docs/vdldocs/facelets/f/view.html).

E.g.

```html
<f:view beforePhase="#{bean.beforePhase}">
    ...
</f:view>
```

with

```
public void beforePhase(PhaseEvent event) {
    if (event.getPhaseId() == PhaseId.RENDER_RESPONSE) {
        // Do here your job which should run right before the RENDER_RESPONSE.
    }
}
```

A more JSF 2.0 way is by the way using the [`<f:event type="preRenderView">`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/javaserverfaces/2.1/docs/vdldocs/facelets/f/event.html):

```html
<f:event type="preRenderView" listener="#{bean.preRenderView}" />
```

with

```
public void preRenderView() {
    // Do here your job which should run right before the RENDER_RESPONSE.
}
```

Comment: This is not related to the topic in anyway. In `event.getPhaseId() == PhaseId.RENDER_RESPONSE` is `==` okay instead of `equals`?

Comment: @gurung: read `PhaseId` javadoc: http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/event/PhaseId.html It's a typesafe constant. In any way, it has no `equals()` overriden and thus inherits `Object#equals()` which does in turn basically already `==`.

Comment: That's what I was expecting. I wanted make sure because I have been using `equals` blindly. Thanks for the explanation.

Comment: @BalusC what if i want to make something after rendering the view not pre rendering, is there's an equivalent phase, or it's done in another way ?

Comment: Do the job in `afterPhase()` method or use `<f:view afterPhase>`.

Comment: and the after phase method should be as follows : `public void afterPhase(PhaseEvent event) {
    if (event.getPhaseId() == PhaseId.RENDER_RESPONSE) {
        
    }
}` or without the if condition ?

Comment: With, of course. The same as in my answer. It will be invoked on every phase the current request is running through.

Comment: @BalusC what is annotation of `<lifecycle><phase-listener></phase-listener></lifecycle>` ? i dont want to write it in `xml` file

Answer (score 5):

In `jsf 2` you can use `<f:phaseListener type="my.MyPhaseListener">` to hook `MyPhaseListener` for some `facelet`. `MyPhaseListener` should implement `PhaseListener` and override

- `afterPhase` - with code to be run after end of phase
- `beforePhase` - with code to be run before phase started
- `getPhaseId` - `PhaseId` enum specifying name of phase for which the listener to be invoked
  (`PhaseId.RENDER_RESPONSE` as last phase of lifecycle)