# How to call bean method on every page request

Tags: jsf-2, jboss, listener

In my work we develop an JSF 2 application. And I need to create a listener bean with one method which have to be executed on every page request. How to accomplish this task?

Comment: be more specific on your requirements, maybe you don't need a bean at all

Comment: You can implement `filter` for that.

Comment: @Vasil Lukach, how to implement filter?

Comment: What do you exactly need to execute? Depending on that you can go with a Filter or a PhaseListener. How to do it depends completelly in your method requirements.

Comment: There are many ways. Please state the concrete functional requirement so that the right way can be proposed. What problem exactly are you trying to solve?

Comment: I have to log the user activity. So that on every page request that user makes I have to call a method which logs the user request.

Answer (score 0):

The answer of your question can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8388854/how-to-implement-a-phaselistener-which-runs-at-end-of-lifecycle).

This method is crucial:

```
public void beforePhase(PhaseEvent event) {
    if (event.getPhaseId() == PhaseId.RENDER_RESPONSE) {
        // Do here your job which should run right before the RENDER_RESPONSE.
    }
}
```

Here you can react on every lifecycle phase and call your apropriate functions inside the needed PhaseId. I hope it helps.

As I see that you use JSF 2, you could also use the following method:

Use this inside your xhtml page:

```
<f:event type="preRenderView" listener="#{bean.preRenderView}" />
```

and call the apropriate method in your bean:

```
public void preRenderView() {
    // Do here your job which should run right before the RENDER_RESPONSE.
}
```

Comment: That's the answer to the question *"How to implement a PhaseListener which runs at end of lifecycle?"* which is not necessarily the same question as *"How to call bean method on every page request"*. Even then, if that answer would have applied, you'd better have voted for close as duplicate instead of blatantly copypasting someone else's answer.

Comment: @BalusC Of course it is not the same question but it can be used in the bean. And as you mentioned in your answer, the `preRenderView` method would also fit his needs

Answer (score 0):

One way to do it is `filter`. Create class:

```
public class MonitoringFilter implements Filter {
    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest _request, ServletResponse _response,
        FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
        HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest)_request;
        HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse)_response;

        // your code here
        chain.doFilter(_request, _response);
    }
}
```

Register it in **web.xml**:

```
  <filter>
    <filter-name>monitoringFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>xyz.MonitoringFilter</filter-class>
  </filter>

  <filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>monitoringFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*.jsf</url-pattern>
  </filter-mapping>
```

(setup proper path in url-pattern).

Answer (score 0):

I solved it. At first I tried with filter but it didn't because the filter is called at begining of the request, but at that time FacesContext is not initialised and I needed because  I have to retrieve the requested url. So after that I tried with phase listener and it works! In beforePhase() method I listen for PhaseId.RENDER_RESPONSE. Thank you all for guidance.