# Is it possible to automatically re-render h:messages on all AJAX calls with JSF2?

Tags: ajax, jsf-2, message, jsf-2.2

I am using an h:messages tag on every page of my JSF2 project to show global messages. I'm also using mostly AJAX to update the page content. As it is right now, I have to include the ID of the h:messages tag in the "render" attribute of every AJAX tag so that it displays any messages that come as a result of that AJAX call. I am wondering, is there some way I can save myself from doing this to every AJAX tag and just tell it to always automatically refresh the messages on any AJAX call?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way is to go with **Primefaces** and its `<p:messages />` component. Using `autoUpdate="true"` gives you the chance to have the message component updated everytime.

**Alternatively**, if not going to use Primefaces and want to avoid having to declare your `h:messages` id each time, you could use backing side updating. Just implement a JSF PhaseListener, which listens to INVOKE_APPLICATION phase and renders your component after it happens:

```
public class JsfPhaseListener implements PhaseListener {

    @Override
    public void afterPhase(PhaseEvent event) {
        FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getPartialViewContext()
                .getRenderIds().add("header:messages");
    }

    @Override
    public void beforePhase(PhaseEvent event) {

    }

    @Override
    public PhaseId getPhaseId() {
        return PhaseId.INVOKE_APPLICATION;
    }

}
```

This will cause your `header:messages` component to be rendered on every single request you make.

**See also:**

- [Primefaces autoupdate in their blog](http://cagataycivici.wordpress.com/2011/04/01/primefaces-autoupdate/)
- [`p:messages` at the showcase](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/messages.jsf)
- [Can I update a JSF component from a JSF backing bean method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11365094/can-i-update-a-jsf-component-from-a-jsf-backing-bean-method)
- [How to implement a PhaseListener which runs at end of lifecycle?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8388854/how-to-implement-a-phaselistener-which-runs-at-end-of-lifecycle)

Comment: Same is true for **Richfaces** `<rich:messages ajaxRendered="true" />` - Tag: http://showcase.richfaces.org/richfaces/component-sample.jsf?demo=messages

Comment: I am not using primefaces so I went with the phase listener method and it works very well! Thank you!

Comment: Glad to see it suits your case!