# How to execute a bean method inside foreach without button or link in jsf?

Tags: jsf, foreach

I am looping a list containing strings in foreach, so in every iteration the variable in foreach loop should be passed as a parameter to a bean method written inside the foreach loop. I searched many sites but everywhere I am finding solution that bean method cannot be executed without commandbutton or link. Is there any solution to execute bean method without any commandbutton or link.

```
<c:forEach var="name" items="#{bean.stringList}" 
 varStatus="loopCounter">

 <!--I have to execute the method here passing "name" as parameter-->

 </c:forEach>
```

Comment: Why you want to do this action in XHTML form if you still want to do it,you need to go asynchronous way.

Comment: http://xyproblem.info

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since [EL](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/el/info) 2.2 you can invoke non-getter methods with arguments. So you could use:

```
<c:forEach var="name" items="#{bean.stringList}" 
           varStatus="loopCounter">
    <c:set var="dummy" value="#{bean.yourMethod(name)}" />
</c:forEach>
```

However, you are most likely are trying to solve something here that can be done in more elegant ways like a `PhaseListener`, a `@PostConstruct` method, a `f:viewAction`, etc.

See also

- [How to implement a PhaseListener which runs at end of lifecycle?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8388854/how-to-implement-a-phaselistener-which-runs-at-end-of-lifecycle)
- [Why use @PostConstruct?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3406555/why-use-postconstruct)
- [When to use f:viewAction / preRenderView versus PostConstruct?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9844526/when-to-use-fviewaction-prerenderview-versus-postconstruct)

Comment: Thanks, it is working and also <h:inputHidden value="#{bean.method(name)}"/>  is working fine.

Comment: You're welcome. Hopefully the related articles were useful as well.